# Is the sequence -んだと missing?

Tags: particles, verbs, relative-clauses

I found this sentence in a textbook:

```
来月までには出来あがらないと思います。
```

It was translated as *"I think that we'll not make it until next month"*.

But the と particle after the negated verb is confusing me. I thought that 出来あがらないと should mean *"If we don't make it, then..."*.

If I understood correctly the ability of the -のだと- sequence to connect complex clauses to verbs such as 思う and 信じる, I would personally say "来月までには出来あがらない**んだと**思います".

So, is my alternative right, or wrong? Plus, am I missing some usage about the と particle? Perhaps before 思う it does not translate as "then", but as a "that" related to the preceding clause?

Comment: You seem rather confused. Are you aware that the particle と has multiple functions? In this case it introduces a (indirect) quote. It is completely different from the conditional と. You could add のだ but that has nothing to do with the way と is functioning here and would change the nuance of the sentence. I suggest you do a little research on quotative

Comment: I admitted that と might not be conditional, given the verb 思う. I know examples of と言う too, even though they were preceded by the quotation marks「」, so as to assure that と denoted a quote. I'm a lower-intermediate learner, and this was the first time I saw a quote without the quotation marks. I'm sure, though, that the sentence "出来あがらないと!" on its own would imply "We gotta make it!" as it literally means "If we dont' make it, then... [sth bad]". But you answered my question, thank you. By the way, in oral communication, should I make a brief pause before と so as to make it quotatitve?

Comment: Quote marks would not be appropriate in this sentence in the same way that writing -- I think "we won't make it" -- is weird with the quotes. You're right that without the verb 思う then と could have been the conditional used as you suggest. As for the pause I think, if at all, it would come after と rather than before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This と is something like a content's marker like "that". Of course, と is used as the conditional such as 来月までには出来あがらないと上司に怒られる.

Your translation for the example is unnatural. -のだ思う is usually used for other's action, not ownself. For example, 彼は明日、会社を辞めるんだと思う is natural, but 私は明日、会社を辞めるんだと思う is unnatural. We say simply 私は明日、会社を辞めると思う.  If the example is "I think that they'll not make it until next month", your translation is good.